# Unable to call an Action from Salesforce Einstein Bot

Tags: salesforce, bots, salesforce-service-cloud, invocable

I am working on my first Salesforce Einstein Bot in a sandbox. The bot works well and navigates through multiple dialogs as intended until I try to call an Action.  If I try to call any action, no matter how simple, the bot automatically ends the chat even though there are more steps in the dialog after the action call.  I have even dumbed-down the invocable method to simply accept a string list and return nothing.  The method literally does nothing and I can call it without issue from a Process Builder.  For some reason in the bot it crashes the chat.  I have deleted and rebuilt the bot from scratch with the same result.

Any thoughts or advice on what I might be missing?  Suggestions on what else I can check?

Comment: Could you provide some specifics? Code snippets, error message, actual methods you called etc., because this is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to give your bot access to the apex class through permission sets. The bot has its own set of permissions name something like sfdc.chatbot.service.permset.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  That did the trick.  It's worth noting that I've had a Salesforce support case open for over a week and they couldn't figure this out.  ;)  Much appreciated.